# php code to generate multiple rows with custom code

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**For Ex-**

**If user input in textbox like**

bookno - 101   totalbook - 2

receiptno - 500   totalrec - 2

coupon - 700      totalcoup - 2

then output comes like below table.

**In this table, coupon no are always unique.and receipt no comes twice bcoz each receipt has two coupon alloted.**

**For Ex-**

book receipt coupon

101 500 - 700

101 500 - 701

101 - 501 - 702

101 - 501 - 703

102 - 502 - 704

102 - 502 - 705

102 - 503 - 706

102 - 503 - 707

**Now second time when i input**

bookcode = 800
book_no2  = 802

receiptcode = 1600
Temp_receipt = 1602

couponcode = 1800
Temp_coupon = 1802

then generate output like below

book   receipt   coupon
801   -1601       1801
801   -1601       -1802
801   -1602      -1803
801   -1602      -1804
802   -1603      -1805
802   -1603      -1806
802   -1604      -1807
802   -1604      -1808

i try below code but not working properly.

```
    <?php 

    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {       

                $bookcode = $_POST['bookcode'];             
                $book_no2 = $_POST['book_no2']; 

                $receiptcode = $_POST['receiptcode'];
                $receipt_no = $_POST['receipt_no']; 

                $couponcode = $_POST['couponcode'];                         
                $coupon = $_POST['coupon']; 

                $Temp_receipt = $receiptcode + $receipt_no;                 
                $Temp_coupon = $couponcode + $coupon;

                for($row1=$bookcode+1;$row1<=$bookcode+$book_no2;$row1++)
                    {   

                    for($row=$receiptcode+1;$row<=$Temp_receipt;$row++)
                        {   

                            $query = $database->getRow("SELECT MAX(receipt_no) AS max1 FROM scheme_master;");
                                if($query['max1']=='')
                                {                           
                                    $largestNumber = $receiptcode;
                                    $top = $largestNumber + 1;                              

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $largestNumber = $query['max1'];
                                    $top = $largestNumber + 1;  
                                }       

                                $Pric = "";                         
                                $loopCount = 0;
                                for($row2=$couponcode+1;$row2<=$Temp_coupon;$row2++)
                                {           

                                    $query = $database->getRow("SELECT MAX(coupon) AS max2 FROM scheme_master;");
                                    if($query['max2']=='')
                                    {                           
                                        $largestcoupon = $couponcode;
                                        $coup = $largestcoupon + 1;                                 
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $largestcoupon = $query['max2'];
                                        $coup = $largestcoupon + 1; 
                                    }   
                                    $value = $loopCount++ + 1;
                                    $code = '- mths';
                                    $Pric=$value.$code;

$insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no2,receipt_no,coupon)
VALUES (:book_no2,:receipt_no,:coupon)", 
array(':receipt_no'=>$top,':book_no2'=>$row1,':coupon'=>$coup));

                            }

                    }
                }
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Books Created Successfully";                        
    }       

?>
```

**I am getting output like below table...**

book receipt coupon

101  -  501  -701

101  -  502  -702

102  -  501  -701

102  -  502  -702

Comment: What output do you get? Without knowing what "not working properly" means, it's a bit difficult to help you. It's also useful to know what **should** be the output

Comment: i updated my output above...plz help ..

Comment: This is a different question to originally posted. Close this one off, start a new question, supply all the information you can, add logging to your code to show values of various variables (and give that in your question too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you use a loop it resets back to the entered value (e.g., coupon_no)

You should use the values for `bookno`, `couponno` and `receiptno` as starting points and the values for `totalbook`, `totalcoup` and `totalrec` as the loop criteria. Increment the numbers as you go:

```
<?php
$bookno= $_POST['bookcode'];               
$totalbook= $_POST['book_no2']; 

$receiptno = $_POST['receiptcode'];
$totalrec= $_POST['receipt_no'];                        

$couponno= $_POST['couponcode'];                            
$totalcoup= $_POST['coupon'];   


for ($book_counter=1; $book_counter<=$totalbook; $book_counter++)
{   

    for($rec_counter=1; $rec_counter<=$totalrec; $rec_counter++)
    {

        for($coup_counter=1; $coup_counter<=$totalcoup; $coup_counter++)
        {   

            $insertrow = $database->insertRow(
                "INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no2,receipt_no,coupon) VALUES (:book_no2,:receipt_no,:coupon)",
                array(':receipt_no'=>$receiptno,':book_no2'=>$bookno,':coupon'=>$couponno));
            $couponno++;
        }
        $receiptno++;

    }
    $bookno++;
}
?>
```

**NB** This has not been tested but it should set you on the right path

Comment: i create this output directly not from code ...but i need this output from code of above input.. i will be grateful to you if you do this..

Comment: What do you get when you run the code? What are the values for the relevant variables on each iteration of the loop? **Add debug code to find errors**. Saying "It goes into an infinite loop" without giving any background as to what is actually happening is not helpful in the slightest

Comment: no sir now this code working properly, not going in any infinite loop but my mean is above code not getting output as i send you for above input...

Comment: DO SOME DEBUG LOGGING AND POST IT HERE! I have no idea what you're expecting, what values you have entered, what code you are using or anything. It's gone from an infinite loop through to working without you telling me what you've done or what you're using

Comment: sir i post my full code now...this is working exactly as i want........but the prob is  i use if else inside receipt and coupon code loop ok....first time when database was empty it generates proper output.....as i want..ok

Comment: but i need when database was not empty  and user put custom start code in receipt and coupon column then data generates from this custom code not from max no.....

Comment: So half your code wasn't in the original question and you only gave half the information that was needed to help you. In future, give the whole code snippet so that we have context.

Comment: Instead of the `SELECT...` queries, use `select if (receipt_no is null,1,max(receipt_no)+1) as max1 from scheme_master;` and remove the `if...then...else` structure. Assign `$top` to be the value of max1. Do the same for `$coup`. `$Pric` is never used and, thus, `$value` and `$code` aren't either. If they are used lower down, you should declare default values for them before this code. Also, learn to add debug code so that it is easier to trace errors. I cannot help you any more

Comment: i tell you my code works first time perfectly but second time this  select receipt and coupon max value and generate according to max value in database.....but i also need second time to start from customstart code and generate like so on...

Comment: my if condition working proper but i also need if condition code in else part ... i try to put the if condition code in else part but wont work for me ....

Answer (score 0):

Edited code (with comments regarding unused variables)

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['save']))
{

    /*
     * No checking for validity of values
     */
    $bookcode = $_POST['bookcode'];
    $book_no2 = $_POST['book_no2'];

    $receiptcode = $_POST['receiptcode'];
    $receipt_no = $_POST['receipt_no'];

    $couponcode = $_POST['couponcode'];
    $coupon = $_POST['coupon'];

    $Temp_receipt = $receiptcode + $receipt_no;
    $Temp_coupon = $couponcode + $coupon;


    for ($row1 = $bookcode + 1; $row1 <= $bookcode + $book_no2; $row1++) // what happens if $bookcode or $book_no2 are negative? Why start at +1 instead of what user entered?
    {

        for ($row = $receiptcode + 1; $row <= $Temp_receipt; $row++) // what happens if $receiptcode or $receipt_no are negative? Why start at +1 instead of what user entered?
        {

            /*
             * Each run of this query will slow down this whole code
             */
            $query1 = $database -> getRow("SELECT if (receipt_no is null, 1,MAX(receipt_no)+1) AS max1 FROM scheme_master;");

            $top = $query1['max1'];

            /*
             * Initialised but $Pric is never used apart from an assignment
             */
            $Pric = "";
            $loopCount = 0; // initialised and updated but not used anywhere in this code
            for ($row2 = $couponcode + 1; $row2 <= $Temp_coupon; $row2++) // what happens if $couponcode or $coupon are negative? Why start at +1 instead of what user entered
            {

                /*
                 * Each run of this query will slow down this whole code
                 */
                $query2 = $database -> getRow("SELECT if (coupon is null, 1, MAX(coupon)+1) AS max2 FROM scheme_master;");
                $coup = $query2['max2'];

                /*
                 * $value is never used
                 */
                $value = $loopCount+=2; // the same as $value=$loopCount++ +1; No idea why it's here as it is not used at all in this code

                /*
                 * These values are never used
                 */
                $code = '- mths';       //unused. As it never changes, should be initialised earlier
                $Pric = $value.$code;   //unused

                $insertrow = $database -> insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no2,receipt_no,coupon) VALUES (:book_no2,:receipt_no,:coupon)", array(':receipt_no' => $top, ':book_no2' => $row1, ':coupon' => $coup));
            }
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Books Created Successfully";
}
?>
```